# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider with filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I've created a filter to replace line breaks by **br**
When I use it the error appears.

The filter:

```
    app.filter('brFilter',function(){
    return function(cadena){
        if(!cadena){
            var nuevaCadena= '';
        }
        else{
            var nuevaCadena= cadena.replace(/\n|\r/g, '<br />');
        }
        return nuevaCadena;
    }
});
```

In DOM:

```
{{unacurriculum.estudios | brFilter}}
```

Why?

Comment: could you please provide the complete code, which will help me find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Sorry, I just restart the server. That works!